# Declaring LinkedList with initital capacity in Java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

LinkedList by nature does not have capacity since it does not allocate memory to the items before the items are added to the list. Each item in a LinkedList holds a pointer to the next in the list. There is no meaning of initial capacity. 
Then why does the piece of code is working in Java?

```
LinkedList<Integer> adjListArray[];
// define the size of array as number of vertices 
adjListArray = new LinkedList[V];
```

Link to the whole program in Java - [Graph Representaions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no initial capacity in this snippet.

You are declaring an array of `LinkedList`s (`adjListArray`), and `V` is the length of that array (i.e. the array can hold references to `V` `LinkedList` instances).